# Navigation component in SXA: dropdown doesn't work when the selected style is "Main Navigation - Drop down vertical"

Tags: sxa

I ran into a weird issue with the navigation component and I can't find what the problem is.

[image]

This is the navigation I have. The selected styles are "Main Navigation - Drop down vertical" and a custom style that adds some spacing (the problem is still there if I remove the custom style.) There should be an FAQs page under About but for some reason the dropdown doesn't work.

If I change the style to "Mobile Navigation" the FAQs link is there:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the navigation settings:

[image]

If you have an idea about what the problem might be I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you check whether the faq navigation item is in the html source when using the drop-down vertical? If so, I will elaborate in an answer as that means you are facing the same issue I had..

Comment: Yes, it's in the html source, and all the right classes for the submenu/dropdown are there but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We noticed this behavior in on of our projects as well and it was acknowledged as a bug (nr 6374) by Sitecore support - so it should be fixed someday but I don't think it already is. We had a navigation that seemed to have the correct elements in the html but didn't show the lower levels.

Luckily it can be easily fixed: what we found was that there is some extra html that gets in the way:

> Apparently the sxa script doesn't take in consideration the extra div
>   on the navigation items. The trigger is on ".rel-level1 > a"  , but
>   the html is something like:
>
> `<li class="level1 submenu item4 odd last rel-level1"> 
>    <div class="field-title"><a title="..."> href="/en/...">...</a></div>`

So the div in the li breaks the trigger. 
This also means it can be fixed it by changing the default rendering variant of the navigation component of SXA:

1. Go to `/sitecore/content/.../Presentation/Rendering Variants/Navigation/Default` in the content editor
2. On each child (NavigationTitle, Title, __Display Name) set the `Tag` field to empty (no more `div`).
3. Publish the variant

You could also create a new variant for this if you want (copy the original and make the changes).